# How to get repeated value counting in my array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have already try like this

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
$arrayName = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,1 );
$arr= array_count_values(array_column($arrayName,'5'));
print_r($arr);
?>
```

I just want to counting of repeated value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using array_column if you only want to count repeated values
you can do this

```
<?php 
  echo '<pre>';
  $arrayName = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,1 );
  $arr= array_count_values($arrayName);
  print_r($arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want count the values

```
$arrayName = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,1 );

$arr =array_count_values($arrayName);

print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

This script counts the amount of each value.

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
$arrayName = [1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,1];
$arr = [];
foreach ($arrayName as $item) {
    if (empty($arr[$item]))
        $arr[$item] = 0;

    $arr[$item] += 1;
}
print_r($arr);
```